# How to customize bootstrap template in Yii2?

Tags: yii, yii2

I want to customize this bootstrap template.
I have template like this:

**Pic 1**

[image]

Actually, I put the html of bootstrap template in `views/layout/main.php`. So, the template will be there consistently. But, I want to make menu in homepage can be different than menu on my template in `views/layout/main.php`. I want to make the menu different. It is like this:
The first page like homepage, the template is like this:

**Pic 2**
[image]

then when I choose the year: 2012, then the page should have like this:

**Pic 3**
[image]

As you see, the different between pic 2 and pic 3 is the "menu" in sidebar. I want to make the menu in pic 3 consistently. So, when I open the other menu, the template stays consistent. It'll be possible when I put the sourcecode in views/layout/main.php. But, what about Pic 2? The page has different menu.

This is my template code in `views\layout\main.php`:

https://pastebin.com/Yd5nQ9Er

Answer (score 1):

Create a different layouts for different pages.You can use layout for specific action and for controller as below :

If you want to use layout for all actions in Controller ,

```
class SiteController extends Controller //controller name
{
    public $layout="main-template-1"; //layout name
     // actions
}
```

If you want to use layout for particular action than use

```
public function actionIndex() // action name
{
$this->layout = "main-template-1"; // layout
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If it is the menu item you want change as seen in the pic1 and pic2 you could 
get the information from the url itself and create if condition on the

```
views\layout\main.php
```

Also if you have different controller you could get the controller and action id by

```
$controller = strtolower(Yii::$app->controller->id);

$action = strtolower(Yii::$app->controller->action->id);
```

and then according to your action and controller you could show hide the menu

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic block:

```
<?php $this->beginBlock('block1'); ?>
...content of block1...
$this->endBlock(); ?>
```

[take a look](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=CJrcDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA90&lpg=PA90&dq=beginBlock()%20yii2&source=bl&ots=lRDxjNeQ0J&sig=BobNu7doj4okC2w8WE5nilSJeeE&hl=uk&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjr8-OA16nVAhViYJoKHciIAGoQ6AEIZTAI#v=onepage&q=beginBlock()%20yii2&f=false)